# How to efficiently apply functions to values in an array based on condition?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have an array `arorg` like this:

```
import numpy as np
arorg = np.array([[-1., 2., -4.], [0.5, -1.5, 3]])
```

and another array `values` that looks as follows:

```
values = np.array([1., 0., 2.])
```

`values` has the same number of entries as `arorg` has columns.

Now I want to apply functions to the entries or `arorg` depending on whether they are positive or negative:

```
def neg_fun(val1, val2):
    return val1 / (val1 + abs(val2))

def pos_fun(val1, val2):
    return 1. / ((val1 / val2) + 1.)
```

Thereby, `val2` is the (absolute) value in `arorg` and `val1` - this is the tricky part - comes from `values`; if I apply `pos_fun` and `neg_fun` to column `i` in `arorg`, `val1` should be `values[i]`.

I currently implement that as follows:

```
ar = arorg.copy()

for (x, y) in zip(*np.where(ar > 0)):
    ar.itemset((x, y), pos_fun(values[y], ar.item(x, y)))

for (x, y) in zip(*np.where(ar < 0)):
    ar.itemset((x, y), neg_fun(values[y], ar.item(x, y)))
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
array([[ 0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.6       ]])
```

As I have to do these calculations very often, I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way of doing this. Something like

```
np.where(arorg > 0, pos_fun(xxxx), arorg)
```

would be great but I don't know how to pass the arguments correctly (the `xxx`). Any suggestions?

Comment: For the `[0,0]` item of the returned value, should the answer be `inf`?  `arorg[0,0]` is negative, so we apply `neg_fun`, which has a denominator of `0`.  `val1 / (val1 + val2) = 1. / (1. - 1.)`

Comment: @James: `arorg[0, 0]` is `-1`, so we indeed apply `neg_fun`; `values[0]` is `1.`. Then we would get: `1. / (1. + abs(-1)) = 0.5`. Where do you see the `inf`?

Comment: Also for [0,3] item, should the result be -1 (2/(-4+2))?

Comment: You didn't include the `abs` in your function

Comment: in your func def, there is no abs()

Comment: @James: It is indeed hidden in the for-loop where I set the values; I update my question; thanks for spotting it!

Comment: @Allen: Yes, it is hidden in my for-loop (see answer to James); I update the question, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the question, here's one using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

First off, we are using a direct translation of the function implementation to generate values/arrays for both positive and negative cases. Then, with a mask of positive values, we will choose between those two arrays using `np.where`.

Thus, the implementation would look something along these lines -

```
# Get positive and negative values for all elements
val1 = values
val2 = arorg
neg_vals = val1 / (val1 + np.abs(val2))
pos_vals = 1. / ((val1 / val2) + 1.)

# Get a positive mask and choose between positive and negative values 
pos_mask = arorg > 0
out = np.where(pos_mask, pos_vals, neg_vals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to apply function to zipped elements of arrays, you can accomplish the same thing through simple array operations and slicing.

First, get the positive and negative calculation, saved as arrays.  Then create a return array of zeros (just as a default value), and populate it using boolean slices of `pos` and `neg`:

```
import numpy as np
arorg = np.array([[-1., 2., -4.], [0.5, -1.5, 3]])
values = np.array([1., 0., 2.])

pos = 1. / ((values / arorg) + 1)
neg = values / (values + np.abs(arorg))

ret = np.zeros_like(arorg)
ret[arorg>0] = pos[arorg>0]
ret[arorg<=0] = neg[arorg<=0]

ret
# returns:
array([[ 0.5       ,  1.        ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.6       ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arorg = np.array([[-1., 2., -4.], [0.5, -1.5, 3]])
values = np.array([1., 0., 2.])
p = 1.0/(values/arorg+1)
n = values/(values+abs(arorg))
#using np.place to extract negative values and put them to p
np.place(p,arorg<0,n[arorg<0])
print(p)
[[ 0.5         1.          0.33333333]
 [ 0.33333333  0.          0.6       ]]
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks (upvoted)! Just a minor thing: `a` is not defined, that should be `arorg`.